# Hyrbid Modul and Program Behaviour for a D Source File

Tags: python, module, executable, d

A Python source file has the nice property of being able to act both as module or as a standalone program (tool) using the pattern

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Is it somehow possible to get the same behaviour for a D module source file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Unix only)

You can use a shebang line that sets a `version` which enables a `main` function:

```
#!/path/to/rdmd --shebang -version=run
version(run) void main() {}
```

Make your file executable (`chmod +x foo.d`) and run it like a program (`./foo.d`).

Be sure to use a unique version identifier (unlike I did here). Maybe include the fully qualified module name in some form, or use a UUID.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you're trying to do. A D program requires exactly one `main` function across all modules as the entry point, so there's not an implicit way as in Python. The D way is to create the executable as a separate module that contains a `main` and imports the other module.

But if you just want to do it for testing purposes, you should put executable code in `unittest` blocks (with no `main`) and then you can run the file using `rdmd -main -unittest scratch.d`, which adds a stub `main` for you.

If you *really* want to make a dual-purpose module (which is not really The D Way), you could put the `main` inside a unique `version` block:

```
module scratch; // file scratch.d
import std.stdio;

void foo(){ writeln("FOO"); }

version(scratchExe) {
    void main() {
        foo();
    }
}
```

Then compile the executable version with `dmd scratch.d -version=scratchExe`.

Answer (score 4):

yes with a [pragma:](http://dlang.org/pragma.html)

```
void foo(){
//...
}

version(fooMain){
pragma(startaddress, foo);
}
```

Comment: `pragma(startaddress)` bypasses the C and D runtime library initialization and should only be used for low-level tasks. It is not applicable for this situation. (How did this get 5 upvotes? This has never and will never work.)